# Eliminate leading zeros on a specific record

Tags: text-processing

Need to eliminate leading zero from the trailer record only.

```
 H|09/24/2015
 D|25.00|Name1|Tfile|5
 D|7.25|Name2|Tfile|1
 T|032.25|03
```

I was able to do this:

```
 sed -e 's/T|0*/T|/g' SampleFileName
```

I got rid of the leading zero on the trailer after the `T|32.25` but not the `03` afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

#### Using sed

If you only want to do the substitution on the last field, you need to anchor the regex to the end of the line:

```
$ sed -Ee '/T/ s/[|]0*([[:digit:]]+)$/|\1/' SampleFileName
 H|09/24/2015
 D|25.00|Name1|Tfile|5
 D|7.25|Name2|Tfile|1
 T|032.25|03
```

`$` matches only at the end of the line.  The (optional) `/T/` condition limits the substitution to lines that contain `T`.

The above was tested on GNU sed but I expect it to work on BSD (OSX) sed also.

#### Using awk

awk divides lines up into fields.  With awk, we can perform the substitution only on the last field (which awk calls `$NF`):

```
$ awk -F'|' '/T/{sub(/^0+/,"",$NF)} 1' OFS='|' SampleFileName 
 H|09/24/2015
 D|25.00|Name1|Tfile|5
 D|7.25|Name2|Tfile|1
 T|032.25|3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use perl as a oneliner command. For example for this problem you can use:

```
 $ perl -p -e 'if (/^T/) { s/\|0*/\|/g } ' SampleFileName
 H|09/24/2015
 D|25.00|Name1|Tfile|5
 D|7.25|Name2|Tfile|1
 T|32.25|3
 $
```

In `if` the regex checks if line start with `T` letter (as I assume those lines are to target) and in `{ }` block regex replacles all zeros after `|` pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Another perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's/\|0+(?=\d)/|/g if /^T\|/;'
```

The above will translate `T|00|` and `T|00.00|` to `T|0|` and `T|0.00|` respectively.